# Simple inline-block of 6 boxes, I add text to a box and it moves vertically down, why?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a lesson on Code Academy. I'm trying to create a row of boxes who represent friends, family, and enemies.

I've created 6 divs with 6 classes. The first and last div have an ID for "best_friend" and "archnemesis" For some reason, once I add text to one of the divs it drops vertically down several pixels and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>My Social Network</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Add your HTML below!-->

        <div class="friend" id="best_friend"></div>
        <div class="friend"></div>
        <div class="family"></div>
        <div class="family"></div>
        <div class="enemy"></div>
        <div class="enemy" id="archnemesis"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.friend{
        border: 2px solid #008000;
    }

.family{
        border: 2px solid #0000FF;
    }

.enemy{
        border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    }
#best_friend{
        border: 4px solid #00C957;
}

#archnemesis{
        border: 4px solid #CC0000;
}
```

Here is a Code sample from Code Academy, which I'm trying to mimic:

https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-jNuXw/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the `vertical-align` property:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    /* change to middle, bottom or baseline to get different alignments */
    vertical-align: top;
  /*vertical-align: middle;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    vertical-align: baseline;*/
}
```

Comment: The explanation code itself doesn't even use a "vertical-align" property. I can't even see a difference between what I did and the code sample, except the fact that it's using <p>'s within the divs

https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-jNuXw/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b

Comment: The problem is the vertical alignment, trust me. https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-jNuXw/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b . Remove the vertical align in this example and see your problem.